# My OneTab extension is not showing anything I have saved. Shows "OneTab restart required. Please quit and restart Chrome."

Tags: brave

OneTab extension in my other web browsers (Edge and Chrome) are working fine but in my Brave browser since several days it is not showing anything  How can i get everthing I have saved back and get this to work again?

[Error "OneTab restart required. Please quit and restart Chrome."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wd47.png)

I have saved to OneTab and says "OneTab restart required. Please quit and restart Chrome." I restarted the browser, I restarted the computer but the issue is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I got this resolved by deactivating (Turning off) the extension and reactivating (Turning on) again in browser's extensions settings. Do not uninstall or delete. Just toggle active switch off and then turn it on again. Then restart the browser.